# What direction does the derivation of an inseparable algebraic variable point in?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, fields, characteristic-p, ramification

I've been thinking about the geometry of inseparable field extensions lately, since I'm studying smoothness in commutative rings in an advanced topics course this semester. I've generally come to the understanding that, given a map between varieties of the same dimension, an inseparable extension at some point of the base corresponds to some kind of branching behavior (ramification). To be precise, any finitely-generated field extension can be broken up into three parts: a purely transcendental part which corresponds to adding more dimensions (by Noether normalization), a separable algebraic part which corresponds to "unfolding" affine space a bit (by the Nullstellensatz), and a purely inseparable part.

From the smooth perspective, the behavior of these different parts can be described by derivations or differentials. (Without any loss of generality, I'll restrict to simple extensions.) A pure transcendental extension $k(x)/k$ has derivation module of rank $1$ freely generated by $d/dx$, which is fairly straightforward. A separable algebraic extension $k[x]/k$ has trivial derivation module, which makes sense because we aren't really adding anything new to affine space, just unfolding some points that were identified by $\operatorname{Gal}(k[x]/k)$. And finally, most curiously, a purely inseparable algebraic extension $k(x)/k$ has derivation module freely generated by $d/dx$.

The first two cases have fairly conventional geometric interpretations. For a transcendental extension, the tangent vector $d/dx$ points in the $x$ direction, i.e. it generates the tangent space of the fiber. For a separable algebraic extension, there is nothing really new and therefore no new direction for a tangent vector to point in. But what about purely inseparable extensions? If $k(x)/k$ is purely inseparable, what "direction" does $d/dx$ point in?

The fact that this phenomenon has no characteristic $0$ analogue makes it non-obvious what the answer should be. One would like to say that, as in a manifold, $d/dx$ points in a direction that represents a change in the fiber variable. The problem is, though, that there is no change in the fiber variable! $x$ is the only root of its minimal polynomial $f(t)$, and the ideal $(f(t))$ ramifies as $(x-t)^{p^n}$, meaning that there's really only one point in the fiber. (Or, perhaps more descriptively, "one point $p^n$ times".) I would like to find an interpretation for this. My most promising-seeming guess so far is inspired by mathematical physics.

In physics, one often considers particles and other objects to be both parts of a system and their own system, and with that comes "internal symmetry" that one needs to deal with. For example, the behavior of electrons in a hydrogen atom is affected by their spin, which is the Noether charge associated to the internal rotational symmetry of the electron (its $\operatorname{Spin}(3)$-symmetry, to be precise). Analogously, I'd like to argue that the fiber over a ramification point has "internal" structure which is described by the differential $d/dx$ but which does not interact with the "external" structure directly.

Is this a legitimate interpretation, and if so, can the internal structure be further described? Moreover, does anyone know if there is a conventional or useful geometric interpretation for this situation?

As an addendum, I'd like to remark that I am familiar with the usual geometric idea that "the fiber over a ramification point is tangent to the total space" with ramification index corresponding to the multiplicity, as described by Mumford and [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618017/geometric-interpretation-of-ramification-of-prime-ideals) (which was somewhat helpful to me). However, in characteristic 0 (where this idea originates), the associated field extension is separable (and possibly trivial), so this still doesn't answer my question: *where does the derivation point?*

Comment: For the sake of transparency, I'll disclose here that I also asked this question on Reddit (/r/math). However, upon reflection, I realized that this was a better place for it, hence the "cross-post".

Comment: First of all, a Zariski point is not really a point. You can only see it through the étale site, where $Spec (k) = BGal (k^{sep}/k)$. Now, a purely inseparable extension is a covering that is excessively ramified. In fact, it's so ramified that every direction points to it (or goes out of it). In the case of finite extensions of function fields, you can think about it as a restriction of a finite covering between Riemann surfaces restricted to an open (actually affine) subvariety decompactified by removing a finite number of points on the base and the respective fibers of those points...

Comment: It might be helpful to look at the definition of a radicial morphism of schemes (e.g., Frobenius).

Comment: You should look at a refinement of the Kähler differentials, namely, the cotangent complex. For example, [Cartier's equality](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07E1) tells you the transcendental degree, which allows you to see the difference between contributions from transcendental elements and purely inseparable elements. Another way to phrase this: field extensions are not smooth in general (while Kähler differentials work well only in "near" smooth case), but still [ind-lci](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07BV). You could also look at Brantner–Waldron.